# 'numeral is not defined' error is appearing if numeral is in html function

Tags: typescript, knockout.js, webpack, numeral.js

I use numeral.js in both the viewmodels and sometimes in the html of my knockout components.

```
<div data-bind="text: numeral(totalCurrent()).format('$0,0.00')"></div>
```

I am using webpack to package my html and js together which seem to work great, however now I get the error 'numeral is not defined' if I try to use numeral in the html markup as shown above.

Numeral works as expected in the viewmodel js just fine.

Any ideas on how I might fix this??

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error as the function `numeral` is not available in the global scope i.e `window` as webpack will wrap everything in a [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE).

You try putting `numeral` onto the global scope in with something like the following.

```
window.numeral = require( 'numeral');
```

Comment: OK, so I added `window.numeral = require('numeral');` in my entry point constructor and it appears to have worked, cheers.

should this also work if the windows.numeral is added to the plugins section of webpack... something like..

`new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    numeral: 'numeral',
    'windows.numeral': 'numeral'
  }),`

Comment: @JasonColey No problem. Using `ProvidePlugin` should also work.